# Are there any workarounds for having a "duplicate" key in a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, key

I'm working on a cashier system/inventory management system, and have run into an issue. My inventory looks like this...

```
inv = Inventory({0:["Boots",34],
                1:["T-shirt",12],
                2:["Jeans", 25],
                3:["Socks", 4]
                })
```

... the key being the barcode scanned, and item details are the values

Normally when the customer scans a barcode, it takes the key-value pair at that specific index (barcode) scanned from the inventory dictionary, and appends it to a shopping cart dictionary.

```
cart = Cart({}, inv)
```

However, if the customer scans the same barcode twice if they want to buy multiple of the same item, the shopping cart dictionary obviously won't have another key-value pair added and instead rewrites the old one with the same information.

Is there any way to get that duplicate item added to the shopping cart dictionary?

Comment: It might totally depend on what you want. You might want to concatenate the new list into the old one, or you can just use a tuple instead of a dict. (But having duplicate keys is not possible in a dict.)

Comment: given your example, you should test if the key is present and update the data (or use a structure that does the job for you like a `defaultdict`)

Comment: Making the shopping cart a dictionary seems like a mistake — what are the keys? Seems like a list might be a better data structure to use for one. A list can have any number of duplicate items in it.

Comment: @martineau thanks for the suggestions, I did decide to turn that dictionary into a list and the program works a lot better, thanks

Comment: That's good to hear…thanks for letting me know.